# Create a new conditional column based on binary values in other columns? (R)

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
A   B   C
1   0   0
0   1   0
0   1   0
0   0   1
```

This is what I’m going for:

```
A   B   C   New_Column
1   0   0   A
0   1   0   B
0   1   0   B
0   0   1   C
```

So I'm creating a new column that tells me which of the three variables (A, B, or C) is present. Only one of the three columns will contain a 1 per row. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `max.col`

```
df1$New_Column <- names(df1)[max.col(df1, "first")]
```